# sdf model not showing in gazebo models list

Tags: gazebo-4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello.

I have made a building layout using building editor and saved the file. Then I made a directory in ~/.gazebo/models/ (named my_world) and copied my sdf file there (named model.sdf). Then I created a simple model.cfg file like in [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=build_robot) tutorial. Now the problem is when I run gazebo and click the insert tab I expect 'My World' to be listed there but it is not there.

Please tell me how I can view my model in gazebo. I am using Gazebo 4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8250/sdf-model-not-showing-in-gazebo-models-list/) by [Huzaifa Qamer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1146/huzaifa-qamer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Huzaifa Qamer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1146/huzaifa-qamer/) on 2015-03-15**:
Never mind I sorted it out. I had named my config file as model.cfg instead of model.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Question answered by author.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0